# MainActivity has leaked window

Tags: android

I am new to Android, I have started only 7 days ago. I'm getting this type of error and also refer most of the topic in the same forum, asked for similar question, but not getting how to resolve.

Here is my code:

```
class CreateNewCustomer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity4.this);
              pDialog.setMessage("Creating Customer..");
              pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
              pDialog.show();
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
              String fname = inputFName.getText().toString();
              String lname = inputLName.getText().toString();
              String phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();

              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
              JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_customer,
                                                           "POST", params);
              Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

              try {
                      int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                      if (success == 1) {
                              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity5.class );
                              startActivity(i);
                              finish();
                      } else {
                              // This is the Else part
                      }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
              pDialog.dismiss();
      }

}
```

Comment: This kind of error comes when you create a popup dialog or some kind of window and then do not remove it and your activity closes.What is your scenario? can you add some more explaination.

Comment: try checking if the the progressdialog.isshowing() when showing and dismissing.

Answer (score 3):

In this part:

```
if (success == 1) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                          MainActivity5.class );
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

before you call `finish()` you need to dismiss the progress dialog. It's not being dismissed hence the window is being leaked and it's causing an exception.

Use this code instead:

```
if (success == 1) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity5.class );
    startActivity(i);
    pDialog.dismiss();
    finish();
}
```

Also, start your new activity from `onPostExecute()`, not `doInBackground()`. Use a flag to check your event for success and start a new activity in `onPostExecute()` like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
    //...
    if (success == 1) {
        successFlag=true;
    }
    //...

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    if(successFlag=true) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity5.class );
        startActivity(i);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks, But still not working.. it being stopped my application as same as before.. any other suggestions..??

Comment: Hello Anup Cowkur.. Thank you so much.. it being worked.. but one question sorry.. Some time it works properly and some time it giving errors the same.. why it happens.. can u give any suggestions..?? as yesterday faced same issue and frustrated... so what to do at that time..?? some time works and some time giving same error and stopped application.. :( 

as it happened before some time.. it was not working.. and after restarting eclipse it works without stopped applications.. so any help will be great for me..

Comment: For the code you have provided, my solution is correct I believe. Please post any more errors you get as another question so that we can help you and it'll help others too. Mark this answer as accepted please. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Never do a startActivity in doInBackground().

Do the startActivity after you dismiss the progress dialog in onPostExecute()

Comment: I have done it same.. have remove start activity from try block and added to onPostExecute after dismiss dialog... but it cant help application stopped as before.. :(